# Drag and Drop to specific place

Tags: javascript

I am just starting to learn basic JavaScript and i got stuck on something I was trying to do. I have four images(1,2,3,4). I want image 4 to only be able to be dropped on image 3. Image 3, only able to be dropped on image 2 and so on. Once the last image is dropped, i want it to open a page. The issue I am having is getting images to only be allowed to drop on another one. How would i go about this? 
This is the code i have so far:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    window.open("button.html", "_self");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the next code

```
    //load "init" when document it's ready
$(document).on('ready',init);

function init() { 
  $( ".img-drop" ).draggable({ containment: "#left"});
  $('.img-drop').droppable( {drop: handleDropEvent}); 
}

// this is what to do when card drops in tardis
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
    var id_drag_element = ui.draggable.attr("id").split('img-')[1];
    var id_drop_element = $(event.target).attr('id').split('img-')[1];
    var last_element = !(!!$('#img-3').length) && !(!!$('#img-3').length);
    if(id_drop_element == 3 && id_drag_element == 4 )
        $('#img-4').remove()
    else if(id_drop_element == 2 && id_drag_element == 3 && !(!!$('#img-4').length)  )
        $('#img-3').remove()
    else if(id_drop_element == 1 && id_drag_element == 2 && last_element   )
    {
        $('#img-2').remove();
        alert('open page...');
        window.open("http://www.google.cl", "_self");
    }
}
```

**Demo**

[JSFinddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johan_16/L48DQ/1/)